# Return the last entry of the 2nd table using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, inner-join, max

This is my first question here, so I'll try to keep it simple.

I have two tables on my "Pendencies System":

**1st** - Main information (such as id, sender, priority...)
**2nd** - Logs of the 1st table (everything that users changes, like title, period...)

I need to show every pendency, linked with the last log of the 2nd table, to get updated info.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are all the columns on the logs table? What defines 'the last log'? Is there a timestamp column?

Comment: you need to post more information about your table structure. What key joins the two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 
  Main JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM
     Logs where Logs.Id in 
        (SELECT MAX(Id) from Logs GROUP BY Logs.Main_Id)
  ) as newestLogs
  ON newestLogs.Main_Id = Main.Id
```

This should approximately work

See http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

for an analysis of how to do the subtable query the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a subQuery to gather the ID and max value from your logs table. Something like below should suffice.

```
SELECT m.id, m.sender, m.priority, l2.*
FROM maininfo m
    INNER JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(PrimaryKey) AS Max
                FROM logs
                GROUP BY id) l ON m.id = l.id
    INNER JOIN logs l2 ON m.id = l2.id AND l.Max = l2.PrimaryKey
```